# Window size incorrect on matplotlib animation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Trying to get an animation of a rotating arrow in a Jupyter notebook.
Can't get the window size and circle display correct.

I'm trying to get an animation of a rotating arrow in matplotlib. This is part of a jupyter engineering mechanics book I'm building for my students.

The idea of the question is that the animation shows what the two dimensional force balance is of multiple vectors on a node (the black dot in the code).

The animation is based on the following three sources:
1) [Drawing a shape](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/drawing-animating-shapes-matplotlib.html)
2) [Matplotlib animation](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/)
3) [Arrow animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033948/arrow-animation-in-python#)

```
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
from math import degrees,radians,cos,sin,atan,acos,sqrt

# Create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Axes labels and title are established
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

ax.set_ylim(-100,100)  #<---- This window size is not displayed
ax.set_xlim(-100,100)  #<---- This window size is not displayed 
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

#the circle
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=10, fc='black')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle) #<---- The circle is not displayed

#arrow1 (more arrows will me added)
arrow1x=[]
arrow1y=[]
arrow1dx=[]
arrow1dy=[]
for t in range(1000):
    if t <= 250:
        arrow1x.append(0)
        arrow1y.append(0)
        arrow1dx.append(t/250*100)
        arrow1dy.append(0)
    elif t <= 500:
        arrow1x.append(0)
        arrow1y.append(0)
        arrow1dx.append(100)
        arrow1dy.append(0)
    elif t <= 750:
        arrow1x.append(0)
        arrow1y.append(0)
        arrow1dx.append(100*cos(radians((t-500)/250*180.)))
        arrow1dy.append(100*sin(radians((t-500)/250*180.)))
    else:
        arrow1x.append(0)
        arrow1y.append(0)
        arrow1dx.append((100-100*(t-750)/250)*-sin(radians((t-750)/250*180.)))
        arrow1dy.append((100-100*(t-750)/250)*-sin(radians((t-750)/250*180.)))

patch = patches.Arrow(arrow1x[0], arrow1y[0], arrow1dx[0], arrow1dy[0])

#the animation (I have no idea how this works:)
def init():
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(t):
    ax.clear() 
    patch = plt.Arrow(arrow1x[t], arrow1y[t], arrow1dx[t], arrow1dy[t])
    ax.add_patch(patch)

    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=1000, interval=20, 
                           blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

As a result of this code I would like to see a square screen with range (-100 x 100,-100 y 100), the black node and the arrow.

What I'm seeing is a square screen (0 x 1,0 y 1), the rotating arrow, and no black dot.

There is no error output in jupyter which makes this really difficult to follow. Additionally the code takes really long to compile, which is also something that is not desired for a webpage, if this keeps taking so long I think i should look in a pre-compiled image (any tips for that perhaps ?).

Thus for some reason the window size and the dot are not adopted, but as far as I'm seeing the code from the sources is adopted as depicted on the webpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You took inappropriate part of "Arrow animation". Since you have static elements on your plot, you don't want to fully clear your `ax`: you should remove one patch during execution of `animate` function. Just replace `ax.clear()` with the next lines:

```
global patch
ax.patches.remove(patch)
```