# Animate arrows in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, vector

I animated a line in matploltib, the output of the code looks like this:

[image]

But what I want is instead of this line the code should plot an arrow (i.e. an arrowhead at the end of the line), here is the code snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax.set(xlim=(0, 104), ylim=(0, 68))

x_start, y_start = (50, 35)
x_end, y_end = (90, 45)

x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 50)
y = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, 50)

line, = ax.plot(x, y)

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, interval=20, blit=True, save_count=50)


plt.show()
```

What should I add/change in the code so that I can get an arrow instead of the line in the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow animation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033948/arrow-animation-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

You can use [`ax.arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html) to plot the arrow.
Note that you should clear the plot with `ax.cla()` and adjust axes limits with `ax.set()` at each iteration.

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax.set(xlim=(0, 104), ylim=(0, 68))

x_start, y_start = (50, 35)
x_end, y_end = (90, 45)

N = 50
x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)
y = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)

def animate(i):
    ax.cla()
    ax.arrow(x_start, y_start,
             x[i] - x_start, y[i] - y_start,
             head_width = 2, head_length = 2, fc = 'black', ec = 'black')
    ax.set(xlim = (0, 104), ylim = (0, 68))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=20, frames=N, blit=False, save_count=50)

plt.show()
```

### Animation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow)

You could simply change the line function to arrow function.
But note that you would first need to calculate the end point of the arrow, since according to the docs, you can only specify the length dx,dy. By using pythagoras, the starting point would be `x[0]`, `y[0]` and `dx`,`dy` is the translated endpoint.

I think you can solve that now on your own.

Comment: This does not work, as the arrow function requires only start points and length, not x-y coordinate pairs, as is requested by the "animate"-function

Comment: I thought geometry is obvious. Put it simply: calculate the respective end point of the arrow by using geometric formula (You have a line with an angle, so use pythagoras...)

Sorry I can't provide a better answer, since I am not on the PC.