# Animated arrows in matplotlib gives IndexError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to animate arrow and used the script from the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914377/animate-arrows-in-matplotlib). Plus my animation has scatter-points and text too.

This is the script that I am using:-

```py
from my_func import Pitch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

## Pitch for plotting the football-pitch in the background
pitch = Pitch(line_color='grey', pitch_color='#121212', orientation='horizontal')
fig, ax = pitch.create_pitch() 

x_start, y_start = (50, 35)
x_end, y_end = (90, 45)

x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 = 50.55, 35.1375, 89.45, 44.8625

x = np.linspace(x_1, x_2, 20)
y = np.linspace(y_1, y_2, 20)

sc_1 = ax.scatter([], [], color="crimson", zorder=4, s=150, alpha=0.7, edgecolor="w")
sc_2 = ax.scatter([], [], color="crimson", zorder=4, s=150, alpha=0.7, edgecolor="w")
title = ax.text(50, 65, "", bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5}, ha="center")

def animate(i):
    if i == 1:
       sc_1.set_offsets([x_start, y_start])
       title.set_text("Start of Action 01")

    if i == 2:
        plt.pause(0.5)
        title.set_text("Action 02")

    ## plot arrow
    ## haven't included ax.cla() as it was removing the pitch in the background
    if i <= len(x):
        patch = plt.Arrow(x_start, y_start, x[i] - x_start, y[i] - y_start)
        ax.add_patch(patch)
    
    ## plot scatter point
    if i > len(x):
        
        plt.pause(0.2)
        title.set_text("Action 03")
        sc_2.set_offsets([x_end, y_end])

    return sc_1, patch, sc_2, title,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(  
    fig=fig, func=animate, interval=50, blit=True)  

plt.show()
```

The result is showing a little bit of animation and then giving me the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 33, in animate
    patch = plt.Arrow(x_start, y_start, x[i] - x_start, y[i] - y_start)
IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20
[1]    14116 abort (core dumped)  python test.py
```

I am a begineer in matplotlib animations and don't know how to solve this error what should I change in my code to remove the error and generate the animated output.

Comment: If `i` equals `len(x)`, then `x[i]` will produce the error you are seeing. You need to modify your `if` statements

Comment: I tried `if i < len(x)` and now it's giving `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'patch' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

The modifications are as follows: 1) `plt.axes()` is added to ax. 2) The return value of the animation function is set to ax. 3) The number of objects to be animated is 20, so `frames=20` is used.

```
# from my_func import Pitch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

## Pitch for plotting the football-pitch in the background
# pitch = Pitch(line_color='grey', pitch_color='#121212', orientation='horizontal')
# fig, ax = pitch.create_pitch() 
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x_start, y_start = 50, 35
x_end, y_end = 90, 45

x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 = 50.55, 35.1375, 89.45, 44.8625

x = np.linspace(x_1, x_2, 20)
y = np.linspace(y_1, y_2, 20)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(50, 90), ylim=(35, 45))
sc_1 = ax.scatter([], [], color="crimson", zorder=1, s=150, alpha=0.7, edgecolor="w")
sc_2 = ax.scatter([], [], color="crimson", zorder=1, s=150, alpha=0.7, edgecolor="w")
title = ax.text(50, 65, "", bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5}, ha="center")

def animate(i):
    if i == 1:
      sc_1.set_offsets([x_start, y_start])
      title.set_text("Start of Action 01")

    if i == 2:
      plt.pause(0.5)
      title.set_text("Action 02")

    ## plot arrow
    ## haven't included ax.cla() as it was removing the pitch in the background
    if i <= len(x):
      ax.clear()
      #patch = plt.Arrow(x_start, y_start, x[i] - x_start, y[i] - y_start)
      #ax.add_patch(patch)
      ax.arrow(x_start, y_start, x[i]-x_start, y[i]-y_start, head_width=1, head_length=1, fc='black', ec='black')
      ax.set(xlim=(50,90), ylim=(35,45))

    ## plot scatter point
    if i == len(x)-1: 
      plt.pause(0.2)
      title.set_text("Action 03")
      sc_2.set_offsets([x_end, y_end])

    return sc_1, sc_2, title, ax

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=20, interval=200, repeat=False, blit=True)  

plt.show()
```

Comment: But I want a single arrow to be displayed, here there are multiple arrow. I have linked one answer in the question itself, I want something like that, but on trying it am getting error.

Comment: I have checked the answer for reference. I have corrected the answer.
The red circles at the beginning and end of the animation are deleted because the arrows are removed each time the animation is done.

Comment: Still not working I tried the above code but its still producting multiple arrows in the animation

Comment: I forgot to copy the function to clear the graph. I updated the code. When I ran it again at hand, the first and last red circles were also displayed, so I removed the attached image