# How to make the arrow blinking without changing its position using matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am new to python but finally seem to get the basic idea of how the animation works in matplotlib.
However, I still can not figure out how to make the arrow to blink on one place pointing to the red circle (both circles remain static and not animated by any means).
I thought that I could make it work just by duplicating the coordinates of the arrow thus making the number of frames to 2 with identic coordinates, but unfortunately it didn't work.
I tried the examples shown here: [Arrow animation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033948/arrow-animation-in-python)
But ax.clear() doesn't suit my needs and ax.patches.remove(patch) for some reason is not working.
The arrow remains static and get the "IndexError: list index out of range" error.
I appreciate any advice!

Output:
[image]

Example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

# Axes labels and title are established
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

ax.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)

# Drawing static circles:
circle1 = plt.Circle((10, 10), 3, color='red')
circle2 = plt.Circle((-10, -4), 2, color='blue')
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)

# Coordinates of the arrow:
x = np.array([2, 2])
y = np.array([2, 2])
dx = x*2
dy = y*2

patch = patches.Arrow(x[0], y[0], dx[0], dy[0])


def init():
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,


def animate(i):
    global patch
    ax.patches.remove(patch)
    patch = patches.Arrow(x[i], y[i], dx[i], dy[i])
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                     frames=len(x), interval=200)

anim.save('222c.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate a blinking artist, the simplest solution is probably to turn the visibility of the artist on and off.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)

circle1 = plt.Circle((10, 10), 3, color='red')
circle2 = plt.Circle((-10, -4), 2, color='blue')
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)

arrow = patches.Arrow(2, 2, 2, 2)
ax.add_patch(arrow)

def animate(ii):
    if ii % 2:
        arrow.set_visible(False)
    else:
        arrow.set_visible(True)
    return arrow,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=200)
anim.save('test.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!
Btw, do you know by any chance why the ax.patches.remove(patch) is not working in my code and throws "IndexError: list index out of range" error?